# Moongose match with field from add field not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql-aggregation

I'm trying to create a query to use with mongoose that allows me to match a string that contains specials characters to a string that doesn't have them.

For example I have the string "PU92US" and I want to match it with "PU-92-US" that is what is in the mongo database.

I have the query for the aggregation/match that is:

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      stringArray: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $strLenCP: "$String",
              },
            ],
          },
          in: {
            $substrCP: ["$String", "$$this", 1],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      filteredArray: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$stringArray",
          cond: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$$this",
              regex: "[0-9a-zA-Z]",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      filteredString: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$filteredArray",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $toUpper: {
              $concat: ["$$value", "$$this"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      filteredString: "PU92US",
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT",
      },
    },
  },
]
```

This works on MongoDB Compass and I can get the match there but isn't working with mongoose on Node.js.

I'm trying to get the result in node.js with the following code:

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection(secrets.database_connection, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, dbName: 'dbName' });
const Model = db.model('modelName', require("../models/modelName"), 'tableName');

let aggTest = await Model.aggregate(query)
```

The result of aggTest always come empty and I can't get the match with the object that does have the string.

Can anyone help me find what i'm doing wrong? Why it's working on MongoDB compass but not in mongoose? I assume the query is correct and I'm maybe trying to use it the incorrect way in mongoose.